# Jest test always pass, using jest to check method request axios

Tags: javascript, typescript, axios, jestjs

i want to check method without sending request , i only want get config to test method and params, i try to do this but test always pass

```
import axios from "axios";
it("get Api Call test", () => {

expect.assertions(1);
axios.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {   
    expect(config.method).toBe("get");
    return config;
}, function (error) {   
    return Promise.reject(error);
});

axios.get("testURL");
```

Anyone know what happen .... i dont want to create mock server ... only want get config to test

Answer (score -2):

Is your goal to assert that a given endpoint/http method were used in the request without making the call and without mocking the server?

I have not used `axios` for this, so I will defer to a library I have used and with great success.

[Nock](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nock) is a great library for testing HTTP requests that you don't want sent. To me, it is better than mocking the server because it is intercepting that request at a higher level than what mocking the server would touch, making it a cleaner test.

To use it, you would have a snippet like:

```js
const nock = require('nock')
it("get Api Call test", () => {
  var expectedReturn = {itDidntReallyHitTheEndpoint: true}
  var requiredPayloadForSuccess = { tmId: "test", name: "foo" };
  nock('thedomain.com')
    .post('/endpoint/to/hit/in/test', requiredPayloadForSuccess)
    .reply(200, expectedReturn)

  const result = await getResult(endpoint, requiredPayloadForSuccess)
  expect(result, expectedReturn)
})
```

This allows you to validate a variety of things. In this example, you will get an error if (this may not be inclusive of all of `nocks` options in this example, it is a very useful tool with many applications)
1) you use the wrong HTTP method
2) you hit the wrong endpoint
3) you don't pass the right payload

You can leave off t he `requiredPayloadForSuccess` if you aren't interested in that feature, but I figured it was worth including.

And to clarify, this intercepts the http request, so you are not actually making the request to that endpoint. The nice part, is everything about your code *thinks* it is.

Comment: sorry for my bad example code , now i edited code i want to check . my project only alows to use axios . then i will try using your way with axios . thanks for yout help. i will try :D

Comment: i dont want to fake response . i only want to check method sending is "get" or not .

Comment: @nghiepnguyentien if you don't want to mock or anything, then wouldn't the test just hit the endpoint and if it used the correct parameters (method, uri, etc) then it works? Is it insufficient that you see the request work instead of trying to intercept and identify the method?